# Understanding / Explanation of Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Here is sample code:

```
with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'Err1, Err2, Err3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'Err1' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.error, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name
```

This query makes a connect by for every row from table temp.

My question is: how is this possible, that cast(multiset( Has Access to table temp data at same level in a subquery? There is a t.error so IT Takes data from t, not with view.

Normally:

```
Select *
From   table1 t1,
       (Select id
        From   table2 t2
        Where  t1.id = t2.id)
```

That kind of query throws error. So how is this working actually?

Comment: Maybe read up on the WITH clause.

Comment: I've read, and like i said - in multiset clause there is T.ERROR, not temp.error

Comment: I see what you are saying.

Comment: Oracle provides an access to the correlation name inside a function (`table` operator in this case) but not in the subquery

Comment: See [table_collection_expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6): *The `collection_expression` can reference columns of tables defined to its left in the `FROM` clause. This is called **left correlation**. Left correlation can occur only in `table_collection_expression`. Other subqueries cannot contains references to columns defined outside the subquery*

Comment: To provide an access to the correlation inside a subquery you need to use `lateral` keyword (ANSI) or `cross|outer apply` (that doesn't require `on`)

Comment: @astentx - so table provides this Access? And inside i can run a subquery ?

Comment: No, just use correlated subquery and lateral join. https://dbfiddle.uk/S3UOcvjZ